# Getting "tree badly conformed; cannot plot. Check the edge matrix" error in R

Tags: r, tree, phylogeny

I am trying to plot a phylogenetic tree using R, however I'm getting the check the edge matrix error. How can I get around this problem? I tried to change the seq value to avoid having NAs. The tree can be plotted just fine with the ott numbers, but I want something decent enough for publication. I'd appreciate any help.

```
library(rncl)
library(rotl)

taxa<-c("Gastrotricha","Platyhelminthes", "Ectoprocta","Brachiopoda","Nemertea", "Mollusca","Annelida","Entoprocta",
        "Cycliophora","Mesozoa","Rotifera", "Gnathostenetroididae","Micrognathozoa", "Chaetognatha","Kinorhyncha",
        "Priapulida","Loricifera","Nematoda", "Nematomorpha","Tardigrada", "Onychophora","Arthropoda","Vertebrata", 
        "rochordata","Cephalochordata", "Hemichordata","Echinodermata", "Xenacoelomorpha", "Cnidaria", "Ctenophora",
        "Placozoa","Porifera")


resolved_names <- tnrs_match_names(taxa)

phyl_tree <- tol_induced_subtree(ott_ids=ott_id(resolved_names)[is_in_tree(ott_id(resolved_names))])

plot(phyl_tree, cex = .8, label.offset = .1, no.margin = TRUE)

name = phyl_tree$tip.label

name[1]=substr(name[1],0,10)
name[2]=substr(name[2],0,10)
name 

new_name=unlist(strsplit(name, split = "_"))[seq(1,54,by=2)]

phyl_tree$tip.label=new_name

plot(phyl_tree, cex = .8, label.offset = .1, no.margin = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from `new_name` not being the same length as the number of tips in your tree:

```
length(new_name) == Ntip(phyl_tree)
```

If you want to have the names updated without the `_ott...` bit, you can use the following code:

```
## Splitting the characters after "_" and keeping only the first element
new_names <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(name, split = "_"), `[[`, 1))
## Replacing the new names
phyl_tree$tip.label <- new_names
## Plotting the updated labels
plot(phyl_tree, cex = .8, label.offset = .1, no.margin = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! The code worked. However, I had to delete two subkingdom taxa, since the ott node_id was not found from the source: 

> /v3/tree_of_life/induced_subtree

Wishing you a one hell of a weekend!